# How do I fix my method so that it only returns letters and not symbols?

Tags: java

I'm working on a simple cipher, switching every letter in the alphabet to its counterpart three spaces away. I did it first by using a method to encrypt the cipher, and am now working on decrypting it. Unfortunately, every letter works except for `abc`, which returns an apostrophe, a hyphen and a blank space. How do I make the loop skip the symbols in ASCII and manage to make it loop back from A to Z?

```
public static String caesarDecrypt(String encoded, int shift){
    String decrypted = "";
     for (int i = 0; i < encoded.length(); i++) {
        char t = encoded.charAt(i);
        if ((t >= 'a') && (t <= 'z')) {
            t -= shift;
        }
        if (t > 'z') {
            t += 26;
        } else if ((t >= 'A') && (t <= 'Z')) {
            {
                t -= shift;
            }
            if (t > 'Z') 
                t += 26;
        } else {

        }

        decrypted = decrypted + t;
    }
    return decrypted;

}
```

Comment: Please describe how exactly you ensured that the result will consist of letters only.

Comment: `"Why does my method return symbols when I've limited it to letters?"` -- limited **what** to letters?

Comment: @PM77-1 I assumed my if statements ensure that my return would only be letters. When I used t += shift and t -= 26, the method only returned characters

Comment: Have you written a small program to test if this assertion is true? A simple program that loops through the letters should suffice.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I tested it in my main method, it worked for encrypting but it's only a, b and c that don't return letters three spaces behind them

Comment: OK. Let's talk regular English alphabet.  What letter comes **before** `A`?

Comment: I suppose it's Z? At least in my case it is since I want the loop to go back to A once it reaches Z

Answer (score 3):

Java `char`s are based on ASCII / UTF values, making the following:

```
a = 97
A = 65
```

(do a search for ASCII tables, etc. to verify)

Based on this, this section of code:

```
if ((t >= 'a') && (t <= 'z')) {
    t -= shift;
}
```

will always shift the characters "down" based on their encoding. Notice that:

```
char(a) - 1 = `
```

this is not exactly an apostrophe, but I can see why you said it was.

The rest of your code is unreachable (or does literally nothing, in the case of the empty `else` block) for these characters, so your cipher does not properly "shift" the first set of lowercase characters in the alphabet.

HINT: this is not the only logical flaw in your cipher... how you handle capital letters should be reviewed more closely.

To assist, you should print out a log of the character integer value before conversion and then after...

EDIT:

A working cipher considers the shift operator appropriately. It may even be greater than 26... so, your `if` statement for lowercase letters should look something like:

```
if ((t >= 'a') && (t <= 'z')) {
    t = (t - 'a' + shift)%26 + 'a';
}
```

and decrementing should be handled with a negative shift value... or a boolean that is passed into the method.

Comment: that makes sense to me now, but how come when I was working forwards with the cipher/encrypting, 'z' didn't move to '{', even though I wrote both methods basically the same way?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you tested, but note that after the faulty block I pointed out here, you have `if (t > 'z') {t += 26;}` so after shifting "z" up once, it was shifted again... probably to an unprintable character so perhaps it went unnoticed?

Comment: well it didn't go unnoticed it gave me the return I was looking for. That's why I'm unsure of how to fix this problem since it worked well in my other method

Comment: well, I illustrated that you do not have a symmetrical cipher - up-shifts and down-shifts are not treated the same. The question you ask now is outside of the scope of your original question, even if it is puzzling or needs a solution.

Comment: So you can't help me at all?

Comment: I am trying to keep to the rules of SO - if you would like to post another question, then please do (and even comment here so people following it know). But if that part of your algorithm works, what question do you have? If you are just trying to find an answer to this question, I think I've provided sufficient information for you to easily figure it out. Right?

Comment: I tried asking it again, but really none of it works. Also I tried switching the ">" signs around and even the plus to minus but I'm still confused. Is there any way I can introduce a modulo operator to it?

Comment: I had done exactly that and I still got the symbols in my return for a,b and c!